# UML Integrated Class Diagram

Tags: uml, terminology, modeling, class-diagram

What is an integrated class diagram? what is the difference between a class diagram and an integrated class diagram? I have searched on google and youtube but could not find a proper explanation.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Where did you read this term? In which context?

Comment: in an assignment

Comment: it seems i have to draw one but i dont understand what it means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no notion of "integrated class diagram" defined in the UML specifications, and it's not a popular term if you search in specialized  publications.

Unless you are learning a custom modelling technique inspired from UML, the term "integrated" shall therefore be taken in its usual [system engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_integration) sense: assembling parts together to make a working whole.

Applied to a class diagram, this would mean to either consolidate several models into a single one (e.g. for the purpose of integrating sub-systems),  or assembling model parts (e.g. if you have separate class diagrams each focusing on specific parts of a system, and then want to show the big picture and how these groups of classes relate to each other).